# UrlHelper.RouteUrl() throws SecurityException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am attempting to host a new ASP.NET MVC site on GoDaddy's Windows hosting.

When building the site navigation, the code uses the `RouteUrl` method from `System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper` to dynamically generate the proper URLs for each page.

Locally, this worked fine. On GoDaddy's server, however, this error is being shown:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +34
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Web.HttpContext.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type service) +54
   System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.GetService(Type serviceType) +13
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.IsUrlRewriterTurnedOn(HttpContextBase httpContext) +108
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext) +13
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +138
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, String protocol, String hostName, String fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl(String routeName, Object routeValues, String protocol) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl(String routeName, Object routeValues) +15
   SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Web.Classes.Navigation.checkPageType(PageModel page, String parentSlug) in Navigation.cs:54
   SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Web.Classes.Navigation.loopNavigation(List`1 navigation, String parentSlug) in Navigation.cs:35
   SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Web.Classes.Navigation.GetNavigation() in Navigation.cs:24
   SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Web.Controllers.BaseController.prepareViewModel(String menu, String subMenu, Action`1 action) in BaseController.cs:34
   SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String menu, String subMenu, String gallery) in HomeController.cs:13
```

The content of the class is below. The `page.Url = _urlHelper.RouteUrl("Default", routeValues);` line in `checkPageType()` is where the error is being thrown.

```
using SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Data;
using SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Data.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SITE_NAME_REDACTED.Web.Classes
{
    public class Navigation
    {
        private IDataRepository _repo;
        private UrlHelper _urlHelper;

        public Navigation(IDataRepository repo, RequestContext context)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            _urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);
        }

        public List<PageModel> GetNavigation()
        {
            List<PageModel> navigation = _repo.GetNavigation();

            return loopNavigation(navigation);
        }

        private List<PageModel> loopNavigation(List<PageModel> navigation, string parentSlug = "")
        {
            List<PageModel> newNav = new List<PageModel>();

            foreach (PageModel page in navigation)
            {
                if (page.Active)
                {
                    checkPageType(page, parentSlug);
                    newNav.Add(page);
                }
            }

            return newNav;
        }

        private void checkPageType(PageModel page, string parentSlug)
        {
            object routeValues;

            if (page.Type == "Collection")
            {
                page.Children = loopNavigation(page.Children, page.Slug);
            }
            else if (page.Type != "Link")
            {
                routeValues = getRouteValues(parentSlug, page.Slug);
                page.Url = _urlHelper.RouteUrl("Default", routeValues);
                page.LinkTarget = "_top";
            }
            else
            {
                page.LinkTarget = "_blank";
            }
        }

        private object getRouteValues(string parentSlug, string pageSlug)
        {
            object result;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentSlug))
            {
                result = new
                {
                    menu = pageSlug
                };
            }
            else
            {
                result = new
                {
                    menu = parentSlug,
                    subMenu = pageSlug,
                    gallery = ""
                };
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, I was able to track it down with the help of [this page on GoDaddy's help site](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-aspnet-2531).

Basically, calling `UriHelper.RouteUrl` triggers a CAS trust level check. GoDaddy defaults to a Medium trust level, but this check requires Full Trust. Following these steps from the linked article resolved the issue:

> ### To Change Your Trust Level
>
> 1. Log in to your GoDaddy account.
> 2. Click **Web Hosting.**
> 3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click **Manage.**
> 4. At the bottom of the section of the domain hosting you want to use, click **Show More.**
> 5. Click **ASP.NET Settings.**
> 6. From the **CAS trust level** menu, select the settings you want, and then click **OK.**